# Using a form and a button to call a method in view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

beginner rails question here. I created a web scraper to populate my model with information and I wanted to call this method with a button from a view. More importantly, I wanted to pass the contents of a form as a parameter to this method. I'm kinda lost on how to this using forms, but so far I have:

I placed the method into the directory app/helpers/admin_pages_helper.rb

```
module AdminPagesHelper
  def populate(term)
  .
  .
  end
end
```

I then have a view located at app/views/admin_pages/index.html.erb

I'm unsure of how to go about this using the form_tag/text_field_tag/submit_tag for a parameter; most of examples I've seen involve database queries using forms instead. Thanks

Comment: What is `term` - a single parameter as a string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest form of usage would be something like this - firstly you need a route that your form can submit to:

```
# in your routes.rb
match "/admin_pages/my_action" => "admin_pages#my_action", as: "my_admin_pages_action"
```

This will route a request to "/admin_pages/my_action" to the "my_action" action in your AdminPagesController.  It also gives you several helper methods you can use to build this url string in your views and/or controllers.

```
# in your view
<%= form_tag my_admin_pages_action_path do |f| %>
  <%= text_field_tag :term %>
  <%= submit_tag "Submit" %>
<% end %>
```

When this form is submitted it will route to the AdminPagesController#my_action method:

```
class AdminPagesController < ApplicationController
  def my_action
    term = params[:term]          # this contains the contents of the text_field
    something = populate(term)    # call your helper method passing in the term
  end
end
```

Comment: I'm getting a "can't convert Symbol into Integer" on the form_for line in view. Any suggestions?

Comment: Are you sure you used `text_field_tag` instead of `f.text_field` on the next line?  Also, try adding a label to the submit button like this: `<%= f.submit "Submit" %>`

Comment: I'm using the text_field_tag. Double checked any typos too.

Comment: Updated to avoid using `form_for` - it's actually intended for building up a model which isn't needed/used here.  I'm not sure why it's not working, but it isn't necessary to fix in this case since you can just replace it with `form_tag`.